# Continuity of the extension of a distribution to $H^s$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $u\in D'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a distribution and suppose that $u$ can be extended to linear functional on $H^s$. Does it follow that $u$ can be extended to a **continuous** linear functional on $H^s$?

Comment: What about $u=\delta_0$ for $s=1$ and $n>1$?

Comment: What do mean by "extended"? If you don't rely on continuity, by choosing bases, you can extend *every* linear functional, but the extension will *never* be unique and almost never continuous.

Answer (score 1):

As martini said: the existence of linear extension in the algebraic sense does not tell you anything. Such an extension can be shown to exist by following the proof of Hahn-Banach theorem without the majorizing functional.